# Use jQuery Signature Pad with hardware capture device

Tags: javascript

We are using jQuery Signature pad http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/. Users want a hardware signing device, similar to the POS devices.

This has to work inside Firefox and Chrome browsers, preferably without ActiveX.

Does anyone have experience with using hardware signature capture devices with browser/javascript plugins? 
The hardware device should have a LCD for user's signature something like : 
http://www.wacom.com/business-and-education/products/pen-displays/stus/stu-300
http://www.topazsystems.com/products/lcdindex.htm

Thank you 
Abhi

Comment: Anything that the OS sees as a mouse should work, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I'd take here is to write a small (native) application that runs on the target computer and has a HTTP server bound to 127.0.0.1 on some port.  The application would interface with the signature pad hardware through its API/SDK, and collect and store signature data in memory.

Your web app would poll this local server via AJAX (IE, `http://127.0.0.1:12345/getSignature`), which would return the signature data as JSON (with the appropriate CORS hreaders, of course) when available or just a HTTP 204 if no signature data is available.

---

If you can't install software on the computer your app will run on, you're dead in the water.  Most hardware signature pads have proprietary APIs that you simply can't access without running privileged code